# Discussion Board Post not in Recent, only under My discussions

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

A user added a new post to a discussion board. It is not showing up under 'Recent', but it is under 'My discussions'. I tested it by creating a new post and same thing.

It appears pressing the 'new discussion' button is bringing up a form but it is not the discussion form (URL is missing the ContentType and RootFolder params).

How do I make the discussion content type the only default content type?

Edit: Discussion is set as the default type.
[image]

If I use the ribbon and select `New Item`, the discussion form is used. Only the `new discussion` button at the top of the thread is loading an alternate form (don't even know which one, don't think it is the message form)

Edit2: Image of form when clicking `new discussion`. Note lack of Question data type.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the **discussion board**, by default, the `discussion content type` is the default one as shown below.

[image]

---

**How do I make the discussion content type the only default content type?**

- Go to List Settings > below Content Types.
- Click on `Change new button order and default content type` as shown in the above image.
- At  `Position from Top` drop-down, chose 1 where **The first content type will be the default content type.**
- In case, you need it as the **only** content type, just uncheck `visible` for other content types.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I updated the question with some more information. I do have the Discussion set as the default but I actually don't have the option to change the order or default. I don't think I can on any Discussion Board.

Comment: do you have any customization? share the form that loaded with new disscu button, also if it's SharePoint online please remove 2013 to can specify the sp version!

Comment: Updated question with form and removed `2013` tag